# Как заставить один сервис обновить второй сервис

Tags: android

Как заставить один сервис обновить второй сервис. Оба запущены постоянно.

Comment: для чего это? что значит обновить?

Comment: Суть такая:
Запущено два сервиса. оба работают постоянно. Один сервис соединяется с сервером, проверяет наличие обновлений для в второго. а вот как происходит обновление (программно). Нужно это для добавления новых функций в первый сервис.

Comment: несовсем понятно, зачем их 2, можно 1 сервис, а в нем 2 потока

Answer (score 1):

Чисто логически вам нужен доступ к директории первого сервиса от имени второго, вызов функции остановки первого, замена нужных файлов, запуск первого сервиса.

Если вы хотите непрерывной работы первого сервиса - единственный путь - оптимизация обновления.

Увы других способов не знаю.

Comment: Какая директория у первого сервиса?